# pyplot - cannot draw dotted line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to draw a scatter plot with a fitted dotted line.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=z, alpha=0.5)
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
y = [(m*i) + b for i in x]
plt.plot(x, y,':' )
```

I attach the result. My problem is that the entire length of the line doesn't appear dotted, only the end of it. I tried to change it to dashed line and again I had the same problem. Is it a problem with the image resolution?

[image]

Comment: It looks like your points down around 0 are very dense, i.e. all the x values will be very very close to each other, leading to your "solid" line.  I will bet that if you zoom WAY in on that line it will be dotted eventually.

Comment: You're right, I zoomed it and it appears dotted. I thought the line would not  be drawn based on the density of the points, only based on the first and last points

Comment: Well, you could plot only the first and last points by changing `plt.plot(x, y,':' )` to `plt.plot([x[0],x[-1]], [y[0],y[-1]], ':')`

Comment: Just tried it, no line is plotted now

Comment: Well, that was pure off-the-cuff typing there ... you know better than I what's in your arrays.  The fact that you're overwriting `y` is a bit suspicious anyway.  I'd just make a brand new x, evenly spaced, and calculate a new y using your fit parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made it work using `plt.plot([min(x),max(x)], [min(y),max(y)], ':')` . If you want add your comments as answer so I can accept it as solution

Comment: Sure thing, made an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire line is dotted; the issue is probably a couple things; that you have points in x very close to each other at the lower values, and they may not be sorted.  In the former case the points are so cramped that the dotted line appears solid unless you zoom way in, and in the latter case the line will overlay itself making it look solid.

You can get around that by only plotting the endpoints of your line, or by creating a new set of sparser x values over which to plot your line fit.

Comment: I think the reason is neither the number of points in x, nor the fact that they are unequally spaced. The problem is that the x values are *not sorted*. Thus the resulting line goes back and forth and overlays itself. Your solution still overcomes the problem though,

Comment: Ah, you may indeed be right; there I go with assumptions again (I'd been assuming they were sorted). I will fold that consideration in.

Comment: Well, my comment is also only an assumption ;)